# How to draw a right triangle in vb.net WinForm?

Tags: vb.net

I have x ImageButtons in my WinForm each ImageButton has the same height and width and works like a radio-button group, the user can press only one ImageButtton at the time.

I would add a triangle at the center of each ImageButton when it's clicked like this:

[image]

I was trying to draw a Triangle by using Graphics but i can't get how to make thar triangle pointing at the Right and anchored to the center of the image button...

Here is the code i've tried to draw the triangle

```
 With e.Graphics
        Using gp As New GraphicsPath
            gp.AddLine(150, 20, 180, 240)
            gp.AddLine(180, 240, 20, 240)
            gp.CloseFigure()
            .FillPath(Brushes.Red, gp)
            .DrawPath(Pens.Red, gp)
        End Using
 End With
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? It looks like a right triangle to me. Is the problem placing it in the centre of the control? I don't see where you've made any effort to do that. If you want something in the centre of a rectangle then obviously you need to calculate that centre, but you've made no effort to do that so you haven't encountered an issue yet.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i've made the example in the picture using photoshop, the triangle drawn with the points in the code has the tip on the top..

Comment: Just like so many people, you seem to want to go from an idea to code without doing the work in between. Calculating the centre of a rectangle and the sides of a triangle is all maths. Where's your maths? Do the maths first and then write code to implement that maths. If you haven't done the maths, which has nothing at all to do with programming, then you shouldn't be thinking about writing code yet and you don't actually have a problem yet.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the main issue as the title of the question was on how to draw the triangle with the tip on the right, all the mats on where to position it will be done then and with that i will have no problems, i've just described in the question even what i will do with that triangle, and the code i've posted is yet drawing a triangle the issue was just to draw it with the tip on right instead of on top as i said firstly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your shoes I’ll pay attention about comments above as if you do that everything will be easier in a long term prospective.
Saying that in a short term this code gives an idea to start with:

```
Private Sub Button2_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Button2.Paint

    Dim w As Single = 30
    Dim h As Single = 50
    Dim centerY As Single = CSng(Button2.Height / 2)

    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality

    Using gp As New GraphicsPath()
        gp.AddLine(0, centerY - h / 2, w, centerY)
        gp.AddLine(w, centerY, 0, centerY + h / 2)
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red, gp)
        e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Red, gp)
    End Using

End Sub
```

And let me add something else which is: your triangle (as your image shows) is a Left triangle not a Right triangle.

Se hai necessità di farlo al click e riportare allo stato iniziale tutti gli altri parti da qui:

```
Private Event UpdateBtns(caller As Button)
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RaiseEvent UpdateBtns(Button1)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Button2.Paint

    AddHandler UpdateBtns, Sub(caller As Button)
                               If (caller.Name <> CType(sender, Button).Name) Then CType(sender, Button).Refresh()
                           End Sub

    If ActiveControl Is CType(sender, Button) Then
        Dim w As Single = 30
        Dim h As Single = 50
        Dim centerY As Single = CSng(Button2.Height / 2)

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality

        Using gp As New GraphicsPath()
            gp.AddLine(0, centerY - h / 2, w, centerY)
            gp.AddLine(w, centerY, 0, centerY + h / 2)
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red, gp)
            e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Red, gp)
        End Using
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It's a right triangle because it has a 90 degree angle.

Comment: :) The first time I hear that about triangles and them sides. Usually is used "the base" as Point of reference as it’s one (or better to say must be one)  Hahahaha. Means today have learn something new.
Right triangle was understood  → positioned in the Right of it’s parent.